# Java ampersand (&) regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex filter that will only allow `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_`, `-`, and the `&` sign.

So far I have this, `"^[A-Za-z0-9_-]$"` but I am unsure on how to include the `&` sign as part of the allowed characters. Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, the "& sign" is called an "ampersand".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `&` inside the character class and make that char class to repeat one or more times by adding `+` quantifier next to that character class.

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9_&-]+$"
```

`[A-Za-z0-9_]` would be written as `\w`.

```
"^[\\w&-]+$"
```

If you want to allow only a single character. Then `+` after the char class won't be needed.

```
"^[\\w&-]$"
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me get it working. I had previously tried adding it in like this `"^[A-Za-z0-9_-&]$"` but was getting errors with that method. Glad I got it fixed.

Comment: i think this would display invalid range quantifier error. It's mainly because of `-` exists between two range patterns. By adding `-` at the start or at the end of char class won't create this error.

Answer (score 3):

`&` has no special meaning in regex. The problem may have been that you added it to the end of your character class, like this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-&]
```

The dash character `-` has special meaning inside a character class *when not first or last* - it is the "range" operator, so by ending with `_-&` you are specifying "all characters between (in unicode order) and including `_` and `&`".

Instead, add the `&` *before* the dash:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_&-]
```

When the dash is first or last in a character class, it's just a literal dash character. This last version should work.